# MongoDB PHP nested documents

Tags: php, mongodb

ok lets say i have this collection in my tv database

```
"season" : "1", "episodes" : {"code" : ["1x01", "1x02", "1x03"], "title" : ["Dont Look Back", "Genesis", "Third"]},
"season" : "2", "episodes" : {"code" : ["2x01", "2x02", "2x03"], "title" : ["D2ont Look Back", "G2enesis", "T2hird"]},
"season" : "3", "episodes" : {"code" : ["3x01", "3x02", "3x03"], "title" : ["D3ont Look Back", "G3enesis", "T3hird"]},
"season" : "4", "episodes" : {"code" : ["4x01", "4x02", "4x03"], "title" : ["D4ont Look Back", "G4enesis", "T4hird"]}
```

how do i make it so that only, lets say the episodes from season 2 are shown?
ive been trying using  
`echo $obj['episodes']['code'][0];` 
but it only shows episodes from the last row

im pretty sure my nesting is all wrong but im new to mongo and im having trouble trying to map this out

any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use find() first.
$a = $coll->findOne(array('season' => '2');
That will return an array $a which will have keys 'episodes', 'title'
So once you find the document with findOne, you would then just access the data using $a['title'] or whatever fields you need